# Merge two 2D arrays into one C++

Tags: c++

I would like to merge two arrays (inventory & inventory2) into one new array (inventory3) for sorting purposes.  I am unable to have inventory3 have values assigned by inventory2 (the second nested for loop).  inventory3 is accepting assignment from inventory correctly.  I cannot figure out why this is not working.  I have been able to verify that the contents of ivnentory2 are correct.

```
void sortInput(string inventory[10][3], int inventory2[10][2]) {
  string inventory3[10][5];
  for (int count = 0 ; count < 10 ; count++) {
    for (int count2 = 0 ; count2 < 3 ; count2++) {
      inventory3[count][count2] = inventory[count][count2];
      cout << inventory3[count][count2] << "\t";
      }    
    for (int count2 = 3, count3 = 0 ; count3 < 2 ; count2++, count3++) {
      inventory3[count][count2] = inventory2[count][count3];
      cout << inventory3[count][count2] << "\t";
      }
    cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste. In order to create such an example, probably all the function `main` must do is call the function `sortInput` with the required arguments.

Comment: The underlying type of `inventory2` is `int`, not `string`. This code cannot possibly compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to assign an `int` to a `string` in this statement:

```
inventory3[count][count2] = inventory2[count][count3];
```

To make it work, convert the `int` to `string` like this:

```
inventory3[count][count2] = to_string(inventory2[count][count3]);
```